# Bootstrap nav tabs aren't switching nor displaying content! [Electron.js] [Bootstrap]

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I can't figure out why

1. The tabs aren't switching when clicked
2. The tabs aren't displaying content

I am using electron and bootstrap, i would appreciate if someone had any reccomendations or solutions. I read a few other similar questions however did not find the answer (as far as i know). 
A snippet is provided. Thanks

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="app-corners">

         <div class="menu-bar">

          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="border-bottom: 0px; background-color: none;" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#1">1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="2-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#2" >2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="3-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#3">3</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="4-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#4">4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          
         </div>


         <div id="container-fluid">
  
          <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="1">

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="2" >
                          <h1>HELLO</h1>


            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="3" >
              <h1>HELLO</h1>


            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="4" >
              
                <h1>HELLO</h1>

            </div>
          </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this one will help you,
please add this link in head tag only.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not used bootstrap js files. Your code is working fine. Check here

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <div class="app-corners">

         <div class="menu-bar">

          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="border-bottom: 0px; background-color: none;" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" id="1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#1">1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="2-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#2" >2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="3-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#3">3</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" id="4-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#4">4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          
         </div>


         <div id="container-fluid">
  
          <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="1">

            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="2" >
                          <h1>HELLO</h1>


            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="3" >
              <h1>HELLO</h1>


            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="4" >
              
                <h1>HELLO</h1>

            </div>
          </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All i needed to do was update the bootstrap version in the header. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="menu-bar">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs"  style="border-bottom: 0px; background-color: none;" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a id="1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#2">4</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="1">
            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="2" >
                          <h1>HELLO</h1>


            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="3" >
              <h1>Hello</h1>


            </div>

            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="4" >
              
                <h1>HELLO</h1>

            </div>
            </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```